# Proper way to set up web server for single-page application

Tags: nginx, web-server, architecture

What I have usually done with single-page applications is to have a single monolithic application server that returns both HTML and responds to AJAX requests. I'd put all AJAX endpoints (typically returning JSON) under a single namespace, say `/api`. All other requests go to a catch-all and return `index.html`.

This seems convoluted, and I'm wondering if there's a standard way to "doing it right".

One method I'm exploring is to set up nginx to route all requests containing the header `accept: text/html` to an application server that just returns the HTML. All requests containing the header `accept: application/json` would be routed to the api server. That seems logical, but I just made that up and for all I know it could be suboptimal.

I'm curious to get feedback as to whether or not there is a standard way of doing this, along with any links that I may have missed during my research.

Comment: What about images, CSS and other static content?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I imagine that'd be served with the static HTML documents.

Comment: Then your existing config is the best way.